# Use same workspace for multiple eclipse instances at same time

Tags: eclipse, workspace

I have two eclipse installed in my system. I want to run the two eclipse at same time and that should use the same workspace. But when I open the second eclipse instance it will prompt something like `the workspace is in use. try different one` . How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can't open **multiple instances** of eclipse on a **single workspace**. But you can open multiple windows on a single workspace.

After first instance opened then click on `Window > New Window` option to open other eclipse window on the **same** workspace.

Comment: Okay. But Opening window won't help me, Because the two eclipse I am using are of different versions. I want that both of them at a time.

Comment: IMHO its not possible. Use two workspace and a single common source repository(git, svn, cvs etc). Why you are using two eclipse version?Why on the same workspace?Any strong reasons?

Comment: Any comments?Edit your post if the answer provided is not OK for you.